# Can I update an iOS 5.0 only app to handle legacy support?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, app-store

I know the best way to go about this would be to offer legacy support in the first place, but my situation won't allow this. My question is will Apple allow me to go back like that, or is it forward progress only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add iOS 4 support to what is now an iOS 5 only app?

Yeah, there is no problem with that. Go for it.

Comment: @Justin - Hey, glad I could help!! Would you be so kind as to mark the answer as 'accepted'? Thanks!!

Comment: I actually have a follow up question for you if you don't mind: if users that had this app before it went to iOS 5.0 only (and couldn't update) kept their app until this new release went live, would they still receive the notice that the app updated to re-include legacy support?